# Combining two python programs in raspberry pi 5

Tags: python

Is there a smooth method to integrate two Python scripts on a Raspberry Pi 5? The first script involves speech recognition, converting spoken words into text. The second script converts text into G-code, specifically formatted for handwriting.

The code for speech recognition is given below:

```
import sys
import typing as t
import time
import whispercpp as w

class StreamTranscriber:
    def __init__(self, model_name: str):
        self.transcriber = w.Whisper.from_pretrained(model_name)
        self.paused = False

    def store_transcript_handler(self, ctx, n_new, data):
        segment = ctx.full_n_segments() - n_new
        cur_segment = ""
        while segment < ctx.full_n_segments():
            cur_segment = ctx.full_get_segment_text(segment)
            data.append(cur_segment)
            segment += 1
        if "hey toaster" in cur_segment.lower() and not self.paused:
            self.transcriber.pause_audio()
            self.paused = True
            print("Stopping")
            time.sleep(5)
            self.transcriber.resume_audio()
            self.paused = False
            print("Resumed")

    def main(self, **kwargs: t.Any):
        transcription: t.Iterator[str] | None = None
        try:
            transcription = self.transcriber.stream_transcribe(callback=self.store_transcript_handler, **kwargs)
        finally:
            assert transcription is not None, "Something went wrong!"
            sys.stderr.writelines(
                ["\nTranscription (line by line):\n"] + [f"{it}\n" for it in transcription]
            )
            sys.stderr.flush()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--model_name", default="tiny.en", choices=list(w.utils.MODELS_URL)
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--device_id", type=int, help="Choose the audio device", default=0
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--length_ms",
        type=int,
        help="Length of the audio buffer in milliseconds",
        default=5000,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--sample_rate",
        type=int,
        help="Sample rate of the audio device",
        default=w.api.SAMPLE_RATE,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--n_threads",
        type=int,
        help="Number of threads to use for decoding",
        default=3,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--step_ms",
        type=int,
        help="Step size of the audio buffer in milliseconds",
        default=0,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--keep_ms",
        type=int,
        help="Length of the audio buffer to keep in milliseconds",
        default=200,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--max_tokens",
        type=int,
        help="Maximum number of tokens to decode",
        default=32,
    )
    parser.add_argument("--audio_ctx", type=int, help="Audio context", default=512)

    parser.add_argument(
        "--list_audio_devices",
        action="store_true",
        default=False,
        help="Show available audio devices",
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.list_audio_devices:
        w.utils.available_audio_devices()
        sys.exit(0)

    transcriber = StreamTranscriber(args.model_name)
    transcriber.main(**vars(args))
```

Where can we add the the text to g-code conversion program code on the above program to run both these programs fluently without time delay?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use one of the scripts as a module.

If I remember correctly, you can then import this module (the G code generator script) in the above code and use all the functions of that module.

That should give you a starting point.

More information about modules can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I'll certainly investigate further and circle back.